# How to insert values in a table having identity column using import wizard in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert values in a table with identity column using import wizard in sql server 2012. 
The table is as below :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Address
        (AddressID int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
        AddressLine varchar(100) NOT NULL,
        City varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        [State] char(2) NOT NULL,
        Zipcode int NOT NULL);
```

Then I created dummy data in excel and saved it as txt file. I followed the steps in wizard, choose the file source as flat file source, choose the correct table, check the Enable identity insert box as well. At the end, it gives me following errors in copying data to the table `dbo.Address`.

```
Error message - 
- Copying to [dbo].[Address] (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AddressID', table 'INFX543_Team8.dbo.Address'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

.

```
   Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - Address.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - Address.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

```
Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Address" (26) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (39). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the insert identity checkbox and also convert the ZiPcode column to Int column.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. It worked out. I have one more doubt. Say I have one more table - CREATE TABLE dbo.VehicleBuyer
  (VehicleBuyerID int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    AddressID  int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Address(AddressID),
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber int NOT NULL,
    EmailID varchar(100) NOT NULL); So in this case while creating dummy data, do I add values to addressID? How the foreign key constraint works with import wizard?

Comment: Hi Kanz, yes you need to add values to addressid in vehiclebuyer table. when you are loading data alter table with no check constraint, do the load and add the constraint again.